# HEIC image format viewer for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, image-viewer

Looking for [HEIC image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) viewer for Windows. Freeware or open source.

Answer (score 1):

[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) can read almost anything you throw at it. I've used it for viewing some really obscure formats. According to [this](https://www.irfanview.com/main_formats.htm) page, HEIC is supported.

It is freeware.